# Navigation link back button not updating after redirection using angularjs $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For redirection in angularjs controller I am using angular `$state.go('menu.tab.cl')` this redirects the user to `cl` view but the back button still keep the previous history state where its been redirected from `cllookup` view. If I add `reload: true`, this displays the home menu which is not what I want.

Current navigation is `Home > Cl > ClList > Cllookup` once redirection complete in the  controller

```
$state.go('menu.tabs.Cl');
```

The URL and View redirects to `Cl` but the back button displays as `<-Cllookup` instead of `<-Cl`

Have tried using

```
$state.go('menu.tabs.Cl', null, {reload: true});
```

but the back button displays as `Home`. Any advise appreciated?

Comment: angular route will be helpful to you.

Comment: @sumitkumar can you explain how angular route will be helpful in achieving ?

Comment: @sumitkumar angular route has nothing to do with this. OP is clearly using ui-router and question is tagged as such

Comment: Have seen this implemented in other apps and its a basic task in app development where you have ability to choose from lookup list and after selecting item you go back to previous view then the back button should display the current view state instead of previous view state. Probably I am doing something wrong here or missing something

Comment: I ended up replacing the view with Modal view and implemented on select list item then redirect route to $state.go(menu.tabs.cl) the back button displays right info now as the Modal doesnt get registered in route which solved the problem. Have also tried angular route its not helpful in this case as the view displays in the parent view not in seperate view as it injects in ui-view directive where ever its placed.